# Libjna build - LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, dll, build, jna, libffi

I'm re-posting an issue from github (https://github.com/libffi/libffi/issues/538) I had since last week.

I'm currently having issue getting some JNA libraries built as jar deployables using Ant build script (FYI: https://github.com/thepaul/libjna-java). in order to use the APIs from this library for my other project. (The sole purpose of me going through the hassle building it is to be able to use its API. Due to lack of documentation and absence of existing build artifact provided, I had to do it myself. Importing the whole libjna repo as a project into my other project maybe another approach but I don't think it's appropriate. That said, if there're any better ways to use the libraries in libjna, do let me know!)

**So here's what I did trying to build it into deployable jar file:**

I already have the source project downloaded.

Tried to compile using Ant (which I downloaded the latest version) on cygwin. Failed because it requires libffi.
So I downloaded libffi source from here (https://github.com/libffi/libffi).

Tried to compile again using Ant. Failed because it couldn't find "/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/vc/bin/cl" as mentioned in the config.log
So I inspected cc.sh and found that it refers to an older version of Microsoft Visual Studio. I have an existing installation of Visual Studio Express. So I changed the path to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x64" in cc.sh file.

Tried to complile again using Ant. Seemed the fix worked but failed with different error because it couldn't find "mspdbcore.dll". I found this file in "..\x86" so I copy the file across to ..\x64

Tried to compile again using Ant. Failed with similar error but different file because it couldn't find "mspdb140.dll". I found this file in "..\x86" so I copied over

Tried to compile again. Failed with different error because now it says

```
"LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'"
```

, although I could confirm this file is definitely in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64"

To tackle this error I tried (in vain):

1. adding microsoft visual studio paths to PATH

   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x64
   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
     Studio\2017\WDExpress\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64
   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\Common7\IDE
2. Downloaded MS Visual Studio 2019 both Community and Professional (couldn't find those dlls for some reason)
3. Downloaded both mspdb140.dll and mspdbcore.dll separately, config.log says it can't find these files

Note I also did some research online, however:

1. I don't use visual studio IDE as I"m only trying to build it with Ant, so this post didn't really help much ([LINK: fatal error LNK 1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356135/link-fatal-error-lnk-1104-cannot-open-file-libcmt-lib))
2. I don't really understand the answer to this post either (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cbedc1ba-c50b-499e-aa2e-12b0ce6a40ba/lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libcmtlib?forum=vclanguage)

So this is where I'm stuck.

See latest config log attached.
[config.log](https://github.com/libffi/libffi/files/4138012/config.log)

Also Ant build log attached.
[ant_compile_error.txt](https://github.com/thepaul/libjna-java/files/4138049/ant_compile_error.txt)

Anyone can help would be much appreciated!

Cheers
Dale

Comment: The linked [libjna-java](https://github.com/thepaul/libjna-java) project looks like it was last updated 9 years ago with JNA version 3.2.7.   The [current JNA project](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) version is 5.5.0.  Is there a reason you have to use the older version of the code?

Comment: Thanks @DanielWiddis, you're right! It turned out I was looking at the wrong source for JNA stuff. Plenty of documentation on the other link (which I originally thought had no particular API I was looking for, hence I looked elsewhere). For those who had similar issue, I do recommend against getting libjna-java repo to work. But instead focus on get your project working with the latest JNA repo as per suggested!